# How to keep Angular 4 template in sync with Google Maps click events

Tags: angular, google-maps, events, rxjs

I need to rely on the Google Maps API which has events that aren't in sync with the change detection system in Angular 4. How do I get them to sync?

```
location = 'some initial value';

ngOnInit() {
  ...
  google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', this.updateLocation.bind(this));
}

private updateLocation(event) {
  this.location = event.latLng.toString();
  console.log(this.location);
}
```

My template always shows the initial value. In the console I do see the updated values.

In AngularJS I would use $applyAsync. I'd like to solve this the 'Angular 4 way' with RxJS but I don't know how to approach it.

See a complete example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/PRUZtaBsVpIjxJSHN3gi?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running code inside angular zone could help you

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', 
       (e) => this.zone.run(() => this.updateLocation(e)));
```

**[Fixed Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Li8SnfHOccsIlriTOpGL?p=preview)**